# Set a target VS_GLOBAL property that applies to all targets using CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

I would like to set a target property that applies to all targets in a CMake project. Specifically, I want to disable vcpkg integration in Visual Studio. I can do it on target by target basis with the following:

```
set_target_properties(${mytarget} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled FALSE)
```

But I don't know how to set globally for all targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a similar problem. The solution I discovered involves setting the properties to all targets.

```
function(get_all_targets var)
    set(targets)
    get_all_targets_recursive(targets ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
    set(${var} ${targets} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
macro(get_all_targets_recursive targets dir)
    get_property(subdirectories DIRECTORY ${dir} PROPERTY SUBDIRECTORIES)
    foreach(subdir ${subdirectories})
        get_all_targets_recursive(${targets} ${subdir})
    endforeach()

    get_property(current_targets DIRECTORY ${dir} PROPERTY BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
    list(APPEND ${targets} ${current_targets})
endmacro()

set_target_properties(${all_targets} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled false)
```

Based on this resource: https://newbedev.com/how-do-i-iterate-over-all-cmake-targets-programmatically